# MongoDB aggregation matching on field in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `Collaborators` as follows:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('xxxx'),
  email: "me@me.com"
}
```

and then a collection called `Initiatives` structured like:

```
[
 {
   title: 'A',
   team: '1',
   Collaborators: [
     { 
        rating: '4',
        role: 'leader',
        email: 'me@me.com'
     },
     { 
        rating: '4',
        role: 'participant',
        email: 'not_me@me.com'
     }
  ]
 },
 {
   title: 'B',
   team: '2',
   Collaborators: [
     { 
        rating: '4',
        role: 'leader',
        email: 'not_me@me.com'
     },
     { 
        rating: '4',
        role: 'participant',
        email: 'not_me@me.com'
     }
  ]
 },
 {
   title: 'C',
   team: '3',
   Collaborators: [
     { 
        rating: '4',
        role: 'leader',
        email: 'not_me@me.com'
     },
     { 
        rating: '3',
        role: 'participant',
        email: 'me@me.com'
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

My goal is to create a MongoDB aggregation that returns the following view:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('xxxx'),
  email: "me@me.com",
  Initiatives: [
     {
       title: 'A',
       role: 'leader',
       rating: '4'
     },
     {
       title: 'C',
       role: 'participant',
       rating: '3'
     },
  ]
}
```

I have got to the point where I can use `$lookup` to include an array of Intitiative objects that match the email, but I can't seem to then 'restructure' this using `$project` to move the Collaborators object up one level and only pulling certain fields ?

Additionally, I was hoping to run `$lookup` as a case-insensitive search as I might need to make varations of me@me.com i.e. ME@me.com

Here is my current `$lookup` routine:

```
{
  from: "Initiatives",
  let: { email: "$email" },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $in: [
            "$$email",
            "$Collaborators.email"
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$Collaborators" },
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            "$Collaborators.email",
            "$$email",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: "Initiatives"
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be this one:

```
db.Collaborators.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Initiatives",
      let: { email: "$email" },
      as: "Initiatives",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [ "$$email", "$Collaborators.email" ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$Collaborators" },
        { $replaceWith: {
           $mergeObjects: [ "$Collaborators", { title: "$title" } ]
           }
        } 
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Initiatives: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Initiatives",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.email", "$email" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "Initiatives.email" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j90ofHEWsgZ)

In order to make it case-insensitive, you could use:

```
let: { email: { $toLower: "$email" } }
```

and

```
$in: [ "$$email", { $map: { input: "$Collaborators.email", in: { $toLower: "$$this" } } } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's close :) I do need to carry some of the 'Initiative' level data through to the array of objects - see the 'title' field in my original questions - and I only need a selection of the 'Collaborators' fields i.e. role and rating. Also, I couldn't get the case-insensitive option to work.

Comment: For the case-insensitivity I updated the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j4cO30tz1xd)

Comment: Unless I am blind, my aggregation pipeline returns exactly what you are asking for. Please provide some details if you are not happy with it.

Comment: When you run your [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Sj_lUE1XfE), I was hoping to see `title: "A"` in the first `Initiative` object and then `title: "C"` in the second one - and I don't necessarily need the `email` field. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks great. Appreciate all your help and patience